# Unable to use ScalaCheck with Scala IDE for Eclipse

Tags: scala, scala-ide, scalacheck

I'm trying to follow the instructions in this guide http://lamp.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lamp/files/teaching/progfun/ScalacheckTutorial.html
in order to use ScalaCheck in Scala IDE.

However, when I create the first file StringSpecification.scala, with this code:

```
package pp.scalacheck

import org.scalacheck._
import Prop.forAll
object StringSpecification extends Properties("String") {
    property("startsWith") = forAll { (x: String, y: String) =>
        (x + y).startsWith(x)
    }
}
```

I get the following error in Scala IDE:

> bad symbolic reference to scala.util.parsing encountered in class file
>   'CmdLineParser.class'. Cannot access term parsing in package
>   scala.util. The current classpath may be missing a definition for
>   scala.util.parsing, or CmdLineParser.class may have been compiled
>   against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the
>   current classpath. (NOTE: It looks like the scala-parser-combinators
>   module is missing; try adding a dependency on "org.scala-lang.modules"
>   : "scala-parser-combinators".        See
>   http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html for more
>   information.)
>
> Error in Scala compiler: bad symbolic reference to
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator encountered in class file
>   'CmdLineParser.class'. Cannot access term combinator in value
>   scala.util.parsing. The current classpath may be missing a definition
>   for scala.util.parsing.combinator, or CmdLineParser.class may have
>   been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found
>   on the current classpath. (NOTE: It looks like the
>   scala-parser-combinators module is missing; try adding a dependency on
>   "org.scala-lang.modules" : "scala-parser-combinators".        See
>   http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html for more
>   information.)
>
> SBT builder crashed while compiling. The error message is 'bad
>   symbolic reference to scala.util.parsing.combinator encountered in
>   class file 'CmdLineParser.class'. Cannot access term combinator in
>   value scala.util.parsing. The current classpath may be missing a
>   definition for scala.util.parsing.combinator, or CmdLineParser.class
>   may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the
>   one found on the current classpath. (NOTE: It looks like the
>   scala-parser-combinators module is missing; try adding a dependency on
>   "org.scala-lang.modules" : "scala-parser-combinators".        See
>   http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html for more
>   information.)'. Check Error Log for details.

I'm using the latest stable version of Scla IDE (for Eclipse) (3.0.4), ScalaCheck (2.11-1.11.6) and Scala (2.11.2), and I'm running on Windows.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Your error says: NOTE: It looks like the scala-parser-combinators module is missing; try adding a dependency on "org.scala-lang.modules" : "scala-parser-combinators". See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html for more information.)'

Did you do that?

Comment: I couldn't find scala-parser-combinators the last time I looked. However, I tried again and found this site which solved the problem: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.scala-lang.modules%7Cscala-parser-combinators_2.11%7C1.0.2%7Cbundle
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I added this jar to the project I was able to build the example files:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.scala-lang.modules%7Cscala-parser-combinators_2.11%7C1.0.2%7Cbundle